# Process fails to exit after being called using AndroidLib.dll

Tags: android, shell

I am working on a HTC One Max Utility that utilizes a AndroidLib.dll.

AndroidLib Git Hub Location: https://github.com/regaw-leinad/AndroidLib

The Classes below are what my code uses to execute the adb shell root command.

```
public static void ExecuteAdbShellCommandInputString(Device device, params string[] inputLines)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            Command.RunProcessWriteInput(AndroidController.Instance.ResourceDirectory + ADB_EXE, "shell", inputLines);
        }
    }

internal static void RunProcessWriteInput(string executable, string arguments, params string[] input)
    {
        using (Process p = new Process())
        {
            p.StartInfo.FileName = executable;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

            p.Start();

            using (StreamWriter w = p.StandardInput)
                for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
                    w.WriteLine(input[i]);

            p.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
```

My command in the code below executes but never exits and my Form program Locks up.

```
        private void unlockboot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false; // to prevent user from spamming the unlock button
        button2.Enabled = false;

        string serial;
        // Setting up the Android ADB Daemon and getting the device serial.
        android = AndroidController.Instance;
        serial = android.ConnectedDevices[0];
        device = android.GetConnectedDevice(serial);
        // Send message to Console Output RichTextBox and executing commands.
        richTextBox1.Clear();
        richTextBox1.Text = "Begin Bootloader Flag Unlock Process.\n";
        Adb.ExecuteAdbShellCommandInputString(device, "su", @"echo -ne 'HTCU' | dd of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p3 bs=1 seek=33796", "exit", "exit");
        richTextBox1.Text += "Completed... Exiting ADB Root.\n";
        button1.Enabled = true;
        button2.Enabled = true;
        button3.Enabled = true;
        // Killing the ADB Daemon and closing out resources.
        android.Dispose();
        richTextBox1.Text += "Your Bootloader has been Unlocked.\n";
        richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
    }
```

This has me stumped I added the exit command to exit from Root in Shell and another to exit the adb shell.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: DLLs are Windows libraries and cannot readily be used on Linux-based environments like Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By implementing a timeout I was able to resolve this issue. WaitForExit(1000)